# How can I override the default config class in custom module in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, adminhtml, frontend, configuration

I want to override Config class using plugin.
Here is my
di.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    
  <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Config">
        <plugin name="ccc_configsecure" type="vendor\module\Plugin\Config" />
    </type>
 </config>
```

My override file

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigTypeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeCodeResolver;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

/**
 * Class Config
 */
class Config 
{
    /**
     * Config cache tag
     */
    const CACHE_TAG = 'CONFIG';

    /**
     * @var ScopeCodeResolver
     */
    private $scopeCodeResolver;

    /**
     * @var ConfigTypeInterface[]
     */
    private $types;

    /**
     * Config constructor.
     *
     * @param ScopeCodeResolver $scopeCodeResolver
     * @param array $types
     */
    public function __construct(
        ScopeCodeResolver $scopeCodeResolver,
        array $types = []
    ) {
        $this->scopeCodeResolver = $scopeCodeResolver;
        $this->types = $types;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve config value by path and scope
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param string $scope
     * @param null|int|string $scopeCode
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getValue(
        $path = null,
        $scope = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT,
        $scopeCode = null
    ) {
        echo "from override";
        exit();
        if ($scope === 'store') {
            $scope = 'stores';
        } elseif ($scope === 'website') {
            $scope = 'websites';
        }
        $configPath = $scope;
        if ($scope !== 'default') {
            if (is_numeric($scopeCode) || $scopeCode === null) {
                $scopeCode = $this->scopeCodeResolver->resolve($scope, $scopeCode);
            } elseif ($scopeCode instanceof \Magento\Framework\App\ScopeInterface) {
                $scopeCode = $scopeCode->getCode();
            }
            if ($scopeCode) {
                $configPath .= '/' . $scopeCode;
            }
        }
        if ($path) {
            $configPath .= '/' . $path;
        }
        return $this->get('system', $configPath);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve config flag
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param string $scope
     * @param null|int|string $scopeCode
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isSetFlag($path, $scope = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, $scopeCode = null)
    {
        return !!$this->getValue($path, $scope, $scopeCode);
    }

    /**
     * Invalidate cache by type
     *
     * Clean scopeCodeResolver
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function clean()
    {
        foreach ($this->types as $type) {
            $type->clean();
        }
        $this->scopeCodeResolver->clean();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve configuration.
     *
     * ('modules') - modules status configuration data
     * ('scopes', 'websites/base') - base website data
     * ('scopes', 'stores/default') - default store data
     *
     * ('system', 'default/web/seo/use_rewrites') - default system configuration data
     * ('system', 'websites/base/web/seo/use_rewrites') - 'base' website system configuration data
     *
     * ('i18n', 'default/en_US') - translations for default store and 'en_US' locale
     *
     * @param string $configType
     * @param string|null $path
     * @param mixed|null $default
     * @return array
     */
    public function get($configType, $path = '', $default = null)
    {
        $result = null;
        if (isset($this->types[$configType])) {
            $result = $this->types[$configType]->get($path);
        }

        return $result !== null ? $result : $default;
    }
}
```

Default Magento File

```
<?php
/**
 * Application configuration object. Used to access configuration when application is initialized and installed.
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Framework\App;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigTypeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeCodeResolver;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

/**
 * Class Config
 */
class Config implements ScopeConfigInterface
{
    /**
     * Config cache tag
     */
    const CACHE_TAG = 'CONFIG';

    /**
     * @var ScopeCodeResolver
     */
    private $scopeCodeResolver;

    /**
     * @var ConfigTypeInterface[]
     */
    private $types;

    /**
     * Config constructor.
     *
     * @param ScopeCodeResolver $scopeCodeResolver
     * @param array $types
     */
    public function __construct(
        ScopeCodeResolver $scopeCodeResolver,
        array $types = []
    ) {
        $this->scopeCodeResolver = $scopeCodeResolver;
        $this->types = $types;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve config value by path and scope
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param string $scope
     * @param null|int|string $scopeCode
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getValue(
        $path = null,
        $scope = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT,
        $scopeCode = null
    ) {
        if ($scope === 'store') {
            $scope = 'stores';
        } elseif ($scope === 'website') {
            $scope = 'websites';
        }
        $configPath = $scope;
        if ($scope !== 'default') {
            if (is_numeric($scopeCode) || $scopeCode === null) {
                $scopeCode = $this->scopeCodeResolver->resolve($scope, $scopeCode);
            } elseif ($scopeCode instanceof \Magento\Framework\App\ScopeInterface) {
                $scopeCode = $scopeCode->getCode();
            }
            if ($scopeCode) {
                $configPath .= '/' . $scopeCode;
            }
        }
        if ($path) {
            $configPath .= '/' . $path;
        }
        return $this->get('system', $configPath);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve config flag
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param string $scope
     * @param null|int|string $scopeCode
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isSetFlag($path, $scope = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, $scopeCode = null)
    {
        return !!$this->getValue($path, $scope, $scopeCode);
    }

    /**
     * Invalidate cache by type
     *
     * Clean scopeCodeResolver
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function clean()
    {
        foreach ($this->types as $type) {
            $type->clean();
        }
        $this->scopeCodeResolver->clean();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve configuration.
     *
     * ('modules') - modules status configuration data
     * ('scopes', 'websites/base') - base website data
     * ('scopes', 'stores/default') - default store data
     *
     * ('system', 'default/web/seo/use_rewrites') - default system configuration data
     * ('system', 'websites/base/web/seo/use_rewrites') - 'base' website system configuration data
     *
     * ('i18n', 'default/en_US') - translations for default store and 'en_US' locale
     *
     * @param string $configType
     * @param string|null $path
     * @param mixed|null $default
     * @return array
     */
    public function get($configType, $path = '', $default = null)
    {
        $result = null;
        if (isset($this->types[$configType])) {
            $result = $this->types[$configType]->get($path);
        }

        return $result !== null ? $result : $default;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override a whole file, you need to use `<preference/>` in **di.xml** file. You need to do the following changes:

> di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">        
      <preference for="Magento\Framework\App\Config" type="vendor\module\Plugin\Config"/>
</config>
```

> vendor\module\Plugin\Config.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace vendor\module\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class Config extends \Magento\Framework\App\Config
{
    public function getValue(
        $path = null,
        $scope = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT,
        $scopeCode = null
    ) {
        echo "from override";
        exit(); 
        if ($scope === 'store') {
            $scope = 'stores';
        } elseif ($scope === 'website') {
            $scope = 'websites';
        }
        $configPath = $scope;
        if ($scope !== 'default') {
            if (is_numeric($scopeCode) || $scopeCode === null) {
                $scopeCode = $this->scopeCodeResolver->resolve($scope, $scopeCode);
            } elseif ($scopeCode instanceof \Magento\Framework\App\ScopeInterface) {
                $scopeCode = $scopeCode->getCode();
            }
            if ($scopeCode) {
                $configPath .= '/' . $scopeCode;
            }
        }
        if ($path) {
            $configPath .= '/' . $path;
        }
        return $this->get('system', $configPath);
    }
}
```

You should add only the methods which you need to override and dependent methods of overridden method in the plugin class file. I have provided solution as per your requirement. But I suggest you that if you to use [Plugins](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) concept. And use  only if you have no way to use Magento Plugins.

Comment: can you please add code of constructure also

Comment: You can call constructor of extended file by using parent::__construct(.....)